# How can I construct this sentence in a better manner?

Tags: sentence-construction, repetition

I wish to construct this sentence in a better manner, avoiding the repeated use of principle. Yet doing away with the repeated word principle in each bullet point will cause the principle name to be read differently.

Suggestions?

> UI design principles focus on improving the quality of user
>   interface design. Some of these principles include:
>
> - Structure principle
> - Simplicity principle
> - Visibility principle
> - Tolerance principle
> - Feedback principle
> - Reusability principle

Comment: You want betterment in 'sentence' or bullet points? And  you **didn't** use the word 'principle' multiple times in your sentence. It's in the bullets. Clarify please

Comment: Any will do...but my concern is that if i remove the repeated "principle" in the bullets, the meaning of the bullets might be changed.

Comment: How does it change? When the **title** reads 'Principles' and the bullets follow, no one would ever think that bullets are **not** principles. That's what the titles' role is, isn't it?

Comment: The sentence includes the bullets as it has a colon and the bullets are in continuation. So it is a single sentence *including* bullets. Surely, that does not deserve a downvote.

Comment: Please see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principles_of_user_interface_design. They do write *principle* for every one of them. I was looking for a better way to write the same thing.

Comment: In the list, is the word "principle" part of an actual nomenclature for the list items? If so, I don't think you can change them.

Comment: see http://csep10.phys.utk.edu/astr161/lect/history/newton3laws.html. Would you consider Laws of Motion as *implied* and omit them?

Comment: True, I second @user3169 Here, the bullet points serve as title and description. I don't think you can change them.

Comment: Added one more option as I think after the clarification in your comment

Comment: My question is clear enough. Does not merit a downvote.

Comment: @MamtaD You can choose to create a table. Will that not work?

Comment: @MaulikV The bullet points occur within the sentence. They are an asyndetic coordination of  noun phrases constituting the Direct Object of the verb *INCLUDE*. So I'm afraid that Matma D **did** use repeated instances of the word *principle* in their sentence.

Comment: @arau bullets are sentences? Interesting. Then why don't they have  periods? The last bullet should have it then.

Comment: @MaulikV They can be, but in this case they are inside the grammatical sentence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of having a multiple co-ordination of entire noun phrases, the Original Poster could just use a co-ordination of modifiers with a single head noun:

> UI design principles focus on improving the quality of user interface design. These principles include the *Structure,  Simplicity,  Visibility,  Tolerance, Feedback*,  and *Reusability* principles.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it this way...

> UI design principles focus on improving the quality of user interface design.

The list of **some of the principles --**

> Structure 
>  
>   Simplicity
>  
>   Visibility
>  
>   Tolerance 
>  
>   Feedback
>  
>   Reusability

**OR**

The **principles of** -

> Structure 
>  
>   Simplicity
>  
>   Visibility
>  
>   Tolerance 
>  
>   Feedback
>  
>   Reusability

Comment: But that is exactly what I DON'T want. I have clearly mentioned that in my question.

Comment: The *only* way to remove a common word in bullet points is to make it a headline/title and then describe the rest. If you **don't** want this, I'm not sure what do you want to express.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can leave out the second "principle". It is implied.

> Some of these include:

As for dealing with the list items, you might write:

> UI design principles focus on improving the quality of user interface design. This might include the **following types**:
>
> Structure
>   Simplicity
>   Visibility
>   Tolerance
>   Feedback
>   Reusability

I am guessing with "types", since I don't know your context in detail. But some synonym of "principles" needs to go here.

Answer (score -1):

I think the best way to go about this is to **either retain it as is** or else **add a small blurb** in front of each bullet point so that the repetition is ***camouflaged*** as given in [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principles_of_user_interface_design).

> UI design principles focus on improving the quality of user interface
>   design. Some of these include:
>
> - Structure principle:
>
>   *(paragraph body)*
> - Simplicity principle:
>
>   *(paragraph body)*
> - Visibility principle:
>
>   *(paragraph body)*
> - Tolerance principle:
>
>   *(paragraph body)*
> - Feedback principle
>
>   *(paragraph body)*
> - Reusability principle
>
>   *(paragraph body)*

Comment: That's what it is, the original. What change you brought in? Did you consider another option - *The principles of...* and then listing them all.

Comment: I didn't mention that change was **mandatory**. I asked for suggestions. Since none of your suggestions were valid, I have mentioned two approaches - one, retain **as is**. Second, **add a blurb or paragraph body**.